# What are these methods and how do I automatically generate them from Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

What are these methods and how do I automatically generate them from Core Data ?

```
@interface MyClass (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addLoanHistoryObject:(CBLoan *)value;
- (void)removeLoanHistoryObject:(CBLoan *)value;
- (void)addLoanHistory:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeLoanHistory:(NSSet *)value;
```

I'm on xCode3
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are "magically" generated for you by XCode. You do that by choosing Add New File ... > NSManagedObject Subclass. Then you specify which Entity from your Model you want a class for, and XCode will generate the files for you, with those methods included. Depending on if you have made the right setup for you relations in Core Data.

Comment: Ya but I actually wanted to know if they are generated for multiple relationships, and for new relationships, if I can just copy paste the code and change the property name... thanks

Comment: You can copy paste the code and change the name, but you have to clean your product and reset the device after you have done a update of your model, so you might as well just delete the model class as well. If you don't want to do that, because you might have added some of your own code to the model class, I suggest that you move that out and into a category to the model class or take a look at mogenerator at: http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/